# Drag&Drop and disappearance ImageView if location ImageView1 = ImageView2

Tags: android, kotlin

I already asked it but some recommended me to read but I write in my question that I already tried and I don't understand. It is the reason because I find help here and I need just example of code. Nobody on russian forums can't help me and StackOverFlow what about i hear so much time and think that it is legendary place but people recommend me to read documentation... I spent a lot of days and didn't have some result. I need example code to finish my 1st and last android app.

I tried:
developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop
and other documentaion. I can read without your help. I want find some example code. I am already hate that I choose it for my final exam in university.

activitymaian.xml

```xml
activity_main.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Main5Activity">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/pop"
            android:id="@+id/draggableImage2" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:contentDescription="draggable"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.101" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.346"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/pop"
            android:id="@+id/draggableImage" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:contentDescription="draggable"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.767" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.215"/>
    <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/basketwaste"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="121dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.026" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activitymain.kt

```
package com.example.fairytale_quest

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener
import android.widget.ImageView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main5.*

class Main5Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5)
    val actionBar = supportActionBar
actionBar!!.hide()
var listener = OnTouchListener(function = { view, motionEvent ->

    if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {

        view.y = motionEvent.rawY - view.height/2
        view.x = motionEvent.rawX - view.width/2
    }

    true


})
draggableImage.setOnTouchListener(listener)
//draggableImage.visibility = View.GONE
draggableImage2.setOnTouchListener(listener)
} }
```

I can drag but I can't delete/disappearance/make invisibility/ etc.

Comment: Can u just help me to find X, Y - coordinate of images? Won't recomend me read, I read already all russian forums and original documentation. StackOverFlow is the last hope